# Hidden files do not display on brand new user accounts?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I just did a fresh install of Windows 7 and my first user account works fine. However, when I create a new user account And go into `Windows Explorer` / `Organize` / `Folder and search options` / `View` / `Advanced settings` and I uncheck `Hide extensions for known file types` and `Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)` as well as check `Show hidden files, folders, and drives`, then hidden files still do not display. Google search results tell me that I have malware, which I obviously do not. Anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: is the new user you made, admin or not?

Comment: Yes. I made two new users and both of them were administrators. I changed the second account to a Standard User, to see if that would fix anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not explain selecting "show hidden files" from the folder option. "Hide extensions for known file types" is not required for this problem. 
If problem still appears try this:
Go to the location of your hidden files in DOS and type: "attrib -s -h -r *.* /s /d"
This sets attribute to your files and folders. Then you may see your files and folder without setting folder option to show hidden files and folder or unchecking hide protected operating system files.

Comment: I'm almost positive I changed that radio button as well, because file extensions are also not displaying. I'll check it out when I can.

Comment: For some reason the radio button was not saving the value, so I launched Windows Explorer as an administrator and changed it. It worked!

Comment: Your answer was what got me thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

You just missed one of the options.  A few lines above the "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)" setting is a little folder symbol that says "Hidden Files and Folders", and underneath that are two radio buttons;  choose the one that says "Show Hidden Files, Folders, and Drives".

[image: folder options]